# What is the difference between running ./gradlew and ./gradlew build?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

What is the difference between running `./gradlew` and `./gradlew build`?

Both seem to be build the project, but `./gradlew` ignore `test` and `compileTest` task.
When test has problem, `./gradlew build` is failed, but `./gradlew` is succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./gradlew` is invoking the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) with no task specified. By default, this displays Gradle version information. This behavior can be changed by settings a [default task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:default_tasks)

`./gradlew build` invokes the Gradle Wrapper with the task named `build`. Therefore, the `build` task executes along with any of its [task dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks).